# Checkbox to Add Text

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have several tables, which are dynamically populated.  On load each checkbox is ticked and each textbox has a value of 1 in it.

I am looking for a jQuery script to run, that if if the checkbox is unticked, then it will replace the textbox with 0 and if it is ticked again, it will replace the zero with a 1.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$('#cb').click(function() {
if($(this).is(':not(:checked'))
$(\"#tx\").val('1');
else
$(\"#tx\").val('o');
});
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for that to work around

Comment: Will do it now - the problem is that the code isn't working though!!

Comment: doens't matter, just provide the code so we get a better context

Comment: Why are you escaping the " marks?  That and a missing ) in your if statement seem to be the issues.

Comment: Escapes were a mistake - http://jsfiddle.net/9NDuB/

Comment: you should not have same id for every textbox

Comment: @DustinCook Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want this:

Without changing IDs and without changing any of your markup.

**Exact solution to your fiddle:**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if(this.checked == true) {
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val("1");

    } else {        
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val("0");

    }
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9NDuB/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a change listener to each checkbox that updates the corresponding textbox. The trick is how you identify the textbox the corresponds to the checkbox. You could use a class or a variation of the checkbox ID (remember that ID's must be unique):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0;
    var txtBoxId = $(this).attr('id') + '_txt'; //in this example, the ID of a textbox is the ID of the checkbox + '_txt'
    $("#" + txtBoxId ).val(val);
});
```

As usual with jQuery, make sure this is in your `ready` function, or else it may appear not to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cb').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':not(:checked)'))
        $("#tx").val('0');
    else
        $("#tx").val('1');
    });
```

This is your code, just cleaned up.

- Added a missing parenthesis after "checked"
- Removed all those oddly escaped " marks around #tx
- Swapped your 0 and 1 to match your rules

Your fiddle has issues as well - you needed to include the jquery libraries on the top left, and as a commenter said, you can't have each thing with the same id.  The code changes I gave you will get most of your stuff working, but the challenge is finding out which textbox to change.  I did so by using a data attribute on each checkbox that says which (unique) id of a textbox to link to.

Check out my working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9NDuB/5/

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$('#cb').change(function() {
    this.checked ? $("#tx").val("1") : $("#tx").val("0");
});
```